# How to add count labels to barplots in Seaborn Facetgrid?

Tags: count, label, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a table as below:

```
data = {'Platform':['Server A', 'Server A', 'Server A', 'Server A', 'Server A', 'Server A', 'Server B', 'Server B', 'Server B', 'Server B', 'Server B', 'Server B', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server C', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D', 'Server D'],
    'Grade':['Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Average','Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Average', 'Average', 'Bad', 'Bad', 'Bad', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Average', 'Average', 'Average', 'Bad', 'Bad', 'Bad'],
    'Colour':['Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green', 'Black', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green', 'Black', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Black'], 
    'Count':[4115314,3879421,4240053,4019764,5398596,5019698,4652935,4140395,4786148,4306763,5691699,5181920,4046690,4202843,5320250,3772534,3945649,4936451,4242814,4490521,5341960,4926092,5095662,5816803,4404762,4587462,5298671,4948988,5146153,5720155]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Platform', 'Grade', 'Colour', 'Count'])
```

And I am looking to create a FacetGrid containing bar plots for the Counts for each Platform, Grade, and Colour.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Platform")
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="Grade", y="Counts", hue="Colour")
g.set_axis_labels("Grade", "Counts")
g.add_legend()
g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", row_template="{row_name}")
```

I am able to get a FacetGrid fine with this code. However, how do I add labels for Counts at the top of each bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a custom function passed to `g.map()`:

```py
def annotate_bars(ax=None, fmt='.2f', **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca() if ax is None else ax
    for p in ax.patches:
         ax.annotate('{{:{:s}}}'.format(fmt).format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                     xytext=(0, 5),textcoords='offset points',
                     ha='center', va='center', **kwargs)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Platform")
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="Grade", y="Counts", hue="Colour")
g.map(annotate_bars, fmt='.2g', fontsize=8, color='k')
g.set_axis_labels("Grade", "Counts")
g.add_legend()
g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", row_template="{row_name}")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Could you share how to fine tune this though? Namely how should I adjust the individual positions so the numbers do not overlap? I've played around with the xytext parameter but it only moves all the numbers at once.

Comment: Given the proximity of some of your bars, I think you will have to play around to find a satisfactory solution. I think you could change the scale of your data to get rid of the exponent (and put "counts in million" in the axis label for instance). You could also consider rotating the annotations 90°